# The Divergence in Euler's Equations

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, partial-differential-equations

Consider the Euler Equations
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{Du}{Dt} + \left< u, \nabla u \right> = \nabla p, \\\\
\text{div} (u) = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
I understand how the first equation is derived, and I get what the second equation represents. But, I am having trouble understanding how the second equation plays a role. Specifically, how do I use it when doing finite differences? (I am not just having this problem with Euler's equations and I am fine if you answer the analogous question for Maxwell's equations instead.)

Answer (score 1):

The second equation plays a role since the unknowns are $p$ and $u$. So you have a system of a vector and a scalar equation and you have three plus one unknowns. 
Without the second equation, the problem would be under-determined.